# get row count of a csv file in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm trying to get the rowcount of a csv file.
I have a csv file in ADLS, and I need to get the row count of that file.
LookUp activity has a limit of 5000 rows, I want to get this only in ADF without using Databricks.

I tried dataflow to get the count of rows
[Source (csvfile) -> DerivedColumn (rowcount) -> Aggregate (count(rowcount)) -> sink (cache the output of aggregate)]

Is there is any other simple way to get the row count of the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row count using copy activity. But this involves ADLS file as source and a SQL table as sink for the copy activity. **So, the dataflow approach is better than this if you want to do this within the ADF itself**.

Take your dataset as source and a SQL table dataset as sink with **Auto create table** option enabled. Give any name for the SQL table.

Execute the copy activity. In the copy activity output, you can get the number of records of the source file.

[image]

Use the below expression to use it further.

```
@activity('Copy data1').output.rowsRead
```

As I mentioned, the dataflow approach is simpler than this which only uses ADLS as source.

Comment: thanks @Rakesh for the solution, I have now used the Dataflow approach for this problem.

Comment: @Tharun, Good to hear that your query was resolved.